# Is there a more efficient way to do pairwise comparisons than this in R?

Tags: r

I am using a function which compares the similarity of each item in a list to each other, like this:

```
sim.items <- outer(items, items, similarity.function)
```

The list is about 11,000 items long and, naturally, this has been running for hours even on a Macbook Pro, 2.4 GHz 8-core, 32GB RAM. Other than optimising the similarity function itself, is there a more efficient way of comparing items pairwise, to produce a similarity matrix (with my custom similarity function)? Should I abandon my approach altogehter?

```
library(tidyverse)

get_all_ngrams <- function(x, N = 3){
  l <- length(x) - N + 1
  stopifnot(l > 0)
  map_df(1:l, function(i){
    ngram <- x[i:(i + N - 1)]
    tibble(start = i, N = N, value = paste(ngram, collapse = ","))
  })
}


similarity.function <- function(x, y, N = 3){
  x <- get_all_ngrams(x, N = N) %>% pull(value)
  y <- get_all_ngrams(y, N = N) %>% pull(value)
  joint <- c(x, y) %>% table()
  tx <- factor(x, levels = names(joint)) %>% table()
  ty <- factor(y, levels = names(joint)) %>% table()
  1 - sum(abs(tx  - ty))/(length(x) + length(y))
}
```

Comment: O(N^2) algorithms gonna O(N^2)

Comment: The two sources of inefficiency here are: (1) `outer`-vs-`combn`, as akrun's answer suggests, `outer` will compute all `n^2` calculations, including self-calcs, which is inefficient; and (2) the function itself might be slow, inefficient, or just computationally hard. We don't know #2, but #1 is clear. With 11000 objects, `outer` will do `1.21e+08` calcs, whereas `combn` is only doing `6.05e+07`, which is (not surprisingly) just under half.

Comment: Bottom line, if your similarity function is symmetric, then `combn` will always do fewer than half the calculations as `outer`. If your function is vectorized, then adjust akrun's answer to *not* use `FUN=`, instead doing as my comment suggests (use of `FUN=` calls the function once per pairing, which if the function is vectorized will be significantly slower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn`

```
combn(items, 2, FUN = function(x) similarity.function(x[1], x[2]),
           simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: And do you believe this would be more efficient (get me a result faster)? If so, why?

Comment: One difference is that `outer` is symmetric, so it compares both 1-v-2 and 2-v-1, I'll infer that the first implies the second in your case. `combn` does not do this, see `combn(5,2)` as an example. The size (and therefore number of "comparisons") of `outer` is `length(x) * length(y)`, whereas the size of `combn` will be `factorial(r)/(factorial(r-n)*factorial(n))` which, when `r` is 2 (as it is here) will be much less (`n` is length of first, and `r` is 2 here).

Comment: @akrun, assuming that `similarity.function` is vectorized, would it not be better to do `z <- combn(items, 2); similarity.function(z[1,], z[2,])`?

Comment: @r2evans I don't know what `similarity.function` is and the question is kind of asking too much to guess and even in the comments, it asks about how this would be efficient without providing a reproducible example

Comment: I don't disagree that there are unanswered concerns. The fact that it is being used in `outer` in the OP means that either it is vectorized or fundamentally broken. If it's vectorized, using `combn(..., FUN=fun)` will be much slower ... but again, we don't know for certain.

Comment: Added code for the similarity.function.